# In grid get image

Tags: laravel, extjs

How can it be done in a grid action column to have a button that, when clicked, can load a photo or file from the hard drive and in the next column visualize what we have selected

How can it be done in a grid action column to have a button that, when clicked, can load a photo or file from the hard drive and in the next column visualize what we have selected?

Comment: "load a photo or file from the hard drive" - hopefully you mean from the application's storage path and your application does not have access to your whole drive

Answer (score 0):

Check the below sample code! When a button in action column is clicked, it updates and visualizes the photo in the previous column for the selected row. The code uses predefined image URLs from the internet. To use your own images stored on the application's server, you would need to implement image uploads and server-side storage, and then modify the code to use the stored image URLs.
Run the below code in [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        // Define separate URLs for loading images
        var imageUrls = [
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&w=1000&q=80",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/09/23/14/22/dahlia-8271071_1280.jpg",
            "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/512882246/photo/dahlia-is-called-orange-garden.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=ltTaeSPKZdo3I7fxewxO0Um_QrPL6kTDxeIXgztLXVE=",
            "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/582297490/photo/bouquet-of-red-roses-on-a-black-background-top-view.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=b1eYs_E8PQ4KW88BbhnjlhULF466pnMze4z_Em7XxV8=",
            "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1175726332/photo/blue-cornflower-herb.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=vqrXLDeUuLCEOwc68XvM0nYBK0xh5ZiEMnp08qrM3CM="
        ];

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'employeeStore',
            fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'photoUrl'], // Change field name to 'photoUrl'
            data: [{
                firstname: "Michael",
                lastname: "Scott",
                photoUrl: ""
            }, {
                firstname: "Dwight",
                lastname: "Schrute",
                photoUrl: ""
            }, {
                firstname: "Jim",
                lastname: "Halpert",
                photoUrl: ""
            }, {
                firstname: "Kevin",
                lastname: "Malone",
                photoUrl: ""
            }, {
                firstname: "Angela",
                lastname: "Martin",
                photoUrl: ""
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Action Column Demo',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'First Name',
                dataIndex: 'firstname'
            }, {
                text: 'Last Name',
                dataIndex: 'lastname'
            }, {
                text: 'Photo',
                dataIndex: 'photoUrl',
                renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
                    if (value) {
                        return '<img src="' + value + '" width="50" height="50"/>';
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 50,
                items: [{
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-cog',
                    text: 'Load Photo',
                    handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                        rec.set('photoUrl', imageUrls[rowIndex]); // Change the index to load a different image
                    }
                }]
            }],
            width: 350,
            height: 800,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```